# operator pow() returns a different value than **

Tags: python, python-3.x

Facing a weird issue here where python's operator.pow is returning a different value than **

```
import operator
pow(-5,0.333)
>> (0.856078889075021+1.4791926873843961j)

-5**0.333
>> -1.709058826000847
```

What am I missing here? I need it to say -1.709 instead of the complex number to work with the rest of my code structure.

Comment: I think I see what's going on now. The minus sign is being evaluated after the power sign by python. So (-5)**0.333 will return the same complex number as operator.pow

Comment: That's not it. Fractional powers of negative numbers are just weird.

Comment: `pow()` has, correctly, returned a complex result. You can't expect a complex result and a scalar result to have the same numbers in them, let alone the same value

Comment: @user207421  try `-3**2` then.  The power operator binds more tightly than unary operators on its left; it binds less tightly than unary operators on its right (see [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#the-power-operator))

Comment: @user207421 Huh? Are you talking about a different language?  The grammar for Python is [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html).

Comment: It seems I am totally wrong about this: my apologies to @wim. The question remains why the Python authors overturned centuries of mathematics and six decades of programming language implementations by changing the precedence of exponentiation. One wonders whether they got the associavity wrong as well: it should be right-associative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python the power operator `**` binds more tightly than unary operators on its left; it binds less tightly than unary operators on its right (see [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#the-power-operator)).

Therefore the correct equivalence to `pow(-5, 0.333)` is `(-5)**0.333`. And the correct equivalance to `-5**0.333` is `-pow(5, 0.333)`.

You may verify the operator precedence with an abstract syntax tree parse / dump:

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.dump(ast.parse("-5**0.333"), annotate_fields=False)
'Module([Expr(UnaryOp(USub(), BinOp(Num(5), Pow(), Num(0.333))))])'
>>> astdump.indented("-5**0.333")  # pip install astdump
Module
  Expr
    UnaryOp
      USub
      BinOp
        Num
        Pow
        Num
```